# Stationary action functional

Tags: calculus-of-variations

The last part in the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equations for a stationary action has me confused. It's about the order of differentiation and evaluation, and whichever comes first.

I'll highlight the derivation and state my question at the end.

### Derivation

---

For Lagrangian $L(q,\dot q)$, denote a variation from the stationary path by
$$
q(t) \to q(t) + \epsilon \eta(t) \equiv \tilde q(t),
$$
from which it follows that
$$
\dot q(t) \to \dot q(t) + \epsilon \dot \eta(t) \equiv \dot{\tilde{q}}(t).
$$

For a stationary action $S=\int L(q,\dot q)d t$, we require that
$$
\delta S \equiv \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\Delta S}{\epsilon}
= \int \frac{1}{\epsilon}\left( 
L(\tilde q,\dot{\tilde{q}}) - L(q,\dot q)
\right)dt =0.
$$
Since $L(\tilde q,\dot{\tilde{q}})$ is a function of $\epsilon$, it can be Taylor expanded:
$$
L(\tilde q,\dot{\tilde{q}}) = 
L(\tilde q,\dot{\tilde{q}})\big|_{\epsilon=0}
+\epsilon\frac{\partial L(\tilde q,\dot{\tilde{q}})}{\partial\epsilon}\big|_{\epsilon=0}
+O(\epsilon^2)
$$
Then, using the chain rule,
$$
\delta S = \int \frac{\partial L(\tilde q,\dot{\tilde{q}})}{\partial\epsilon}\big|_{\epsilon=0} dt
= \int \left(
\left[
\frac{\partial L(\tilde q,\dot{\tilde{q}})}{\partial \tilde q}
\frac{\partial \tilde q}{\partial \epsilon}
\right]\bigg|_{\epsilon=0}
+
\left[
\frac{\partial L(\tilde q,\dot{\tilde{q}})}{\partial \dot{\tilde{q}}}
\frac{\partial \dot{\tilde{q}}}{\partial \epsilon}
\right]\bigg|_{\epsilon=0}
\right)dt =0
$$
and after partial integration (with vanishing boundary term)
$$
\delta S = 
\int \left(
\frac{\partial L(\tilde q,\dot{\tilde{q}})}{\partial \tilde q}
\bigg|_{\epsilon=0}
-\frac{d}{dt}
\frac{\partial L(\tilde q,\dot{\tilde{q}})}{\partial \dot{\tilde{q}}}
\bigg|_{\epsilon=0}
\right)\eta dt =0.
$$
Given the arbitrary character of $\eta$, it follows that
$$
\frac{\partial L(\tilde q,\dot{\tilde{q}})}{\partial \tilde q}
\bigg|_{\epsilon=0}
-\frac{d}{dt}
\frac{\partial L(\tilde q,\dot{\tilde{q}})}{\partial \dot{\tilde{q}}}
\bigg|_{\epsilon=0} 
=0.
\quad (1)
$$

---

## Question

The mathematics say that in Eq. (1) we now *first* should calculate the partial derivatives, and *then* evaluate at $\epsilon=0$, to get the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$
\frac{\partial L(q,\dot{q})}{\partial q}
-\frac{d}{dt}
\frac{\partial L(q,\dot{q})}{\partial \dot{q}}
=0.
$$
If it were the order way around (first evaluating $\epsilon=0$), I would understand it, but not when first evaluating the derivative.

In other words, is it justified to say that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}
\frac{\partial L(\tilde q,\dot{\tilde{q}})}{\partial \dot{\tilde{q}}}
\bigg|_{\epsilon=0}
=
\frac{d}{dt}
\frac{\partial \left(
L(\tilde q,\dot{\tilde{q}})
|_{\epsilon=0}
\right)}{\partial 
\left( \dot{\tilde{q}}
|_{\epsilon=0}
\right)
}
\qquad
\left(
=
\frac{d}{dt}
\frac{\partial L(q,\dot{q})}{\partial \dot{q}} 
\right)
?
$$

Comment: I haven't had a proper course in calculus of variations, but can't you just treat $\epsilon$ as if it were a parameter of $x$ and just plug in after differenation?